# Extra character in sendKeys method in selenium 3.0.1

Tags: selenium, textbox, character, sendkeys

SendKeys method in selenium 3.0.1 puts an extra special character everytime in the begining of textbox resulting in the failure of method.
[image]

Please find the special character enclosed in red coloured box.

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: what about 3.0.0 ? if it's working this could be a selenium bug.

Comment: myEditBox.clear();
myEditBox.sendKeys(Keys.HOME,Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.END));
myEditBox.sendKeys(value);

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have tried, etc. into the question properly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely something to do with you sending HOME and END keys. I'm not sure why you would need that here after using `.clear()`. Just use the below.

```
myEditBox.clear();
myEditBox.sendKeys(value);
```